# Kentico 10: How do I change accordion pane headers?

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I'm using the accordion layout that comes standard with Kentico 10, but I'm at a loss as to how I'm able to edit all the individual pane headers.

Through the webpart configuration I can change the 1st pane by updating **Pane Headers**. But that's as far as I can go.

Please, can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to widget configuration
[image]

Edit the layout property of the widget:

[image]